# Dynamic Web Form Based on Rights and Permissions

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, permissions, webforms

Need to design several ASP.Net Web Forms that change based on User Type and Permission Levels.

There are seven User Types defined in the database (ClientType Table, ID = 0-7).

All Fields in the database that will map back to controls in our Web Forms are also defined by User Type with View/Add/Modify/Delete permissions and stored in a seperate table in the database.

ie

```
tbl_FieldAccess

FieldName = Client_Name (Client Name Field in our Client Table)
ClientType = 1
View = 1
Add = 0
Modify = 0
Delete = 0

FieldName = Client_Name ClientType = 7
View = 1
Add = 1
Modify = 1
Delete = 1
```

What is the best way (patterns, practices, specific examples) to now take my actual web form controls and map them to the records in my tbl_FieldAccess table and then use that to determine whether or not to show/hide the control, make it readonly, etc.?

Note: I have to use legacy login and authentication so ASP.Net Membership API is not an option here.

Using ASP.Net, C# and SQL Server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm recommending you to create a view model for your pages:

```
class MyPageViewModel
{
    public bool SendButtonVisible { get; set; }
    public bool EditButtonEnabled { get; set; }
    // many other properties ...
    public YourData Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then your aspx looks like:

```
<asp:Button Id="btnSend" runat="server" Visible='<%# Model.SendButtonVisible" %>' />
```

And your code behind:

```
    public class YourPage : Page
    {
         public MyPageViewModel Model 
         {
             get { return (MyPageViewModel )ViewState["Model"]; }
             set { ViewState["Model"] = value;  }
         }

         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                // put all business logic in your service layer
                Model = YourServiceClass.GetMyPageViewModel();
                DataBind();
            }
         }
    }
```

Comment: I like it. I will give it a try and see how it goes and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: it's looks good, but how do i know what page is currently loaded and getting that particular form rights.we are currently loading the form name in Database and getting the particular form rights.please tell me the best way to compare the currently selected form is equal to  stored form in database

Comment: @VGSNaidu You should Enable/Disable controls to reflect user's permissions. For example if you have an user with AdminRole and this role contains permissions for message sending, then you will set SendMessageButton on SendMessagePage to visible.